# Error Compiling Publish (Sundell) from Manifest File

Tags: installation, swift-package-manager

TLDR;

I installed John Sundell's Publish according to the accepted practices and immediately get an error when I try to build my site package. How do I successfully install the product?

---

---

After cloning the publish package:

```
git clone https://github.com/JohnSundell/Publish.git
```

I cd'd into the Publish folder and ran:

```
make
```

which created an executable at `/usr/local/bin/publish`

I opened a new terminal window, created a directory using `mkdir Saturday` and then cd'd into that folder. I typed `publish new` and was successful:

```
✅ Generated website project for 'Saturday'
Run 'open Package.swift' to open it and start building
```

When I open the manifest file (Package.swift) and type cmd-S (Save) it imports all the necessary packages, and everything looks good to go.

When I type cmd-B (Build), however this error message comes up:

```
The package product 'CollectionConcurrencyKit' requires minimum platform version 13.0 for the iOS platform, but this target supports 11.0
```

When I look at the clone/install of Publish I see:

```
Computing version for https://github.com/johnsundell/collectionConcurrencyKit.git
Computed https://github.com/johnsundell/collectionConcurrencyKit.git at 0.1.0 (0.37s)
```

Notice it says version 0.1.0. In the generated package for my site, it retrieves version 0.2.0.  I don't know if that's an issue.

But not one other Package.swift file in all the fetched dependencies mentions iOS.

I have this line in my Package.swift

```
   platforms: [.macOS(.v12)],
```

So I know **I haven't added this dependency on iOS inadvertently**, so I don't understand the error message.

I'm running `macOS Monterey 12.6` on Xcode 14.0 (14A309) - both are the most recent release versions available.

The hardware is: MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) using the `Apple M1 Pro` chip

If I'm leaving anything out, please comment and I'll provide more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `slap your forehead` ‍♂️ kind of thing here.

It turns out that when I opened the Package.swift it defaulted to an iOS scheme that I had just been using.  I updated the scheme to a macOS based one, the problem went away.  Now I understand the source of the iOS error. Apparently the two versions of ConcurrencyKit is a red herring.

Hope this helps others! Always check your target when compiling.

Comment: Don't feel bad, that happens to me all the time: the scheme gets mysteriously changed, I don't notice, and then Weird Stuff happens.

Comment: In case anybody else comes across this, also check the target destination. I received this when I had an iPad selected as the destination and not my Mac.